# Andengine (GLES 2), code compiled into .JAR instead of .APK

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to build my first Android application project in Eclipse IDE with Andengine as library. It's compiled OK, but when I try to run there is an error that says:

`[2012-07-01 07:18:08 - Android] Could not find Android.apk!`.

I'm following this tutorial : http://perle-development.com/tutorials/andengine-tutorial-01-creating-a-scene/

Comment: What is the name of the jar file and the project?

Comment: The project name is Android and the jar file is Android.jar, when I try to run it up, it won't run, instead producing that jar file in bin folder

Comment: Do you have a script like exportToJar or something? Did you create a new project, or replace/change code in an existing one?

Comment: no, I do not use any script, it's just usual android project, I don't know what's wrong with it. When I create Android project without andengine, it works fine, but when I added the andengine library (like one suggested in: [link](https://jimmaru.wordpress.com/2012/04/23/setting-up-andengine-gles2-0/), section using andengine GLES2.0, it produces jar file and won't run in my emulator

Comment: Oh, sorry, got it, it happens because I checked 'IsLibrary' that I shouldn't checked it :)..

Comment: Read somewhere Gles 2.0 doesnt work in emulator. Im not sure

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out. Just make sure 'IsLibrary' unchecked.